# For-loop nested in an if-statement Vs. an if-statement nested in a for-loop

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, if-statement

This question is mostly about optimizing a script's performance by switching the order of an if-statement and a for-loop.
I have a code that is a bit similar to the one below (I removed all unnecessary bits for simplification purposes). I wrote the three alternatives that came to mind.
Version 1:

```
for rowindex in range(400):
    for columnindex in range(10):
        exec(f'{something}1 = ...')
        if comparisonbool:
            exec(f'{something}2 = ...')
```

Version 2:

```
for rowindex in range(400):
    if comparisonbool:
        for columnindex in range(10):
            exec(f'{something}1 = ...')
            exec(f'{something}2 = ...')
    else:
        for columnindex in range(10):
            exec(f'{something}1 = ...')
```

Version 3:

```
if comparisonbool:
    for rowindex in range(400):
        for columnindex in range(10):
            exec(f'{something}1 = ...')
            exec(f'{something}2 = ...')
else:
    for rowindex in range(400):
        for columnindex in range(10):
            exec(f'{something}1 = ...')
```

So, while I find version 1 to look nicer, I was wondering if versions 2 or 3 would result in a significantly better performance.
My reasoning is that, in version 3, the if-statement if checked only once and then the code runs based on its result. In version 2, it is checked 400 times. In version 1, it is checked 4000 times

However, I tried timing it by using time.perf_counter() [I ran it directly before and after my loops and calculated the difference between the two].
I timed 6 runs for each of the three versions and got the following average run times: Tv1: 0.56s , Tv2: 0.50s, Tv3: 0.53s
I believe the differences in timing are insignificant and caused by random variables, since repeating my experiment gives different results (sometimes v3 is the fastest, other times v1, etc...)

My question is: **given the insignificant performance differences, should I just stick to version 1,  or would versions 2 or 3 be considered for some reason more "pythonic"?**

I tried searching for posts that discuss this by comparing different ordering options, but wasn't able to find any.
I consider myself to be relatively new to python and this is my first post on this website so I hope my question is formulated well and easily understood.

Comment: If you care about performance, you shouldn't be using `exec`. Get rid of those calls, change to using a list or dictionary, then I'd re-evelauted to see if performance is still even a concern. I wouldn't be too concerned about the performance of `if obj:` though. Any built-in or sane user-defined object should have `__bool__` methods that return instantly. I'd definately stick with what reads better until you have good reason to suspect that code in particular.

Comment: Version 4 is a possibility, depending on what kind of assignments you are making. `for row in ...: for column in ...: for key, value in X: d[key] = value`, where the value of `X` is determined ahead of time using `comparisonbool`.

Comment: Code for readability and maintainability, until performance becomes a measurable concern. Also consider using an array (aka list) for "something"

Comment: Thank you all, and especially @Carcigenicate , for your helpful suggestions: both for putting into context the if-statement's low impact and for pointing out the potentially greater impact of the `exec` function . I had focused so much on the ordering of the `if`/`for` that I had overlooked the impact of using the `exec`. Removing it improved the script's performance a great deal.